# Why Date.tomorrow > Time.now return false in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

See the RoR pry console result:

```
[1] pry(main)> Date.tomorrow > Time.now
=> false
[2] pry(main)> Date.tomorrow.to_time > Time.now
=> true
[3] pry(main)> Date.tomorrow
=> Tue, 07 Oct 2014
[4] pry(main)> Time.now
=> 2014-10-06 22:52:40 -0400
```

Added timestamp result to let you know the rough values.

Comment: It's worth noting that `Date.tomorrow > Time.now` returns `true` for me right now. This is time of day dependent.

Comment: You are right, it return different result based on when you run it, untrusty statement, shouldn't use it in code.

Answer (score 8):

Because `Date.tomorrow` is tomorrow and `Time.now` *in UTC* is also tomorrow.

You'll notice you are doing this at `10:52pm` (e.g. `EST`)
but that is actually `2:52am` **tomorrow** (given the `-0400` difference)

Thus as tomorrow is not "greater than" tomorrow, that is false.

If you changed it to `>=` it might then pass.

As you've found though, a workaround is use tack on `.to_time`

Comment: Awesome answer, it's indeed time dependent, now I got true for that statement. I should not use this statement in code!! Weird bug caused by it.